# How can i disable spring boot actuator elastic search health requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot app that **uses local elastic search** and Spring Boot Actuator 2.1.2 only for metrics purposes. Now i need to implement a default health check, so i turned it on in my configuration application.properties class like this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=...,health
management.endpoint.health.show-details=never
```

It works fine and i can achieve a health status using default implementation calling http://localhost/actuator/health.

But there is a moment that i don't like. I've found that each time when i get a non-detailed answer like `{"status":"UP"}` actuator makes a needless elasticsearch call at

```
ElasticsearchHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder)
```

I'm planning to get rid of useless calls.

Can i somehow disable only this call?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try with the below properties in application.properties file

```
management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=false
```

Comment: I can't do this, because i use HealthIndicator bean in my metrics purposes. Setting this properties to false leads to bean dependency error. I hope there is a way to handle it via some customization of health service...

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the default health check, create a custom health check class and use that.

Something like the custom HealthCheck, found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-health-indicators